# Why I am getting array of Null values when using xpath function to extract elements from XML string in PySpark

Tags: python, xml, pyspark, xpath

I have a csv file with only one column called "Data". Column Data has only one record which contains a nested xml string as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Customers>
        <Customer CustomerID="1">
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Address>
                <Street>123 Main St</Street>
                <City>Anytown</City>
                <State>CA</State>
                <Zip>12345</Zip>
            </Address>
            <PhoneNo>123-456-7890</PhoneNo>
        </Customer>
        <Customer CustomerID="2">
            <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
            <Address>
                <Street>456 Oak St</Street>
                <City>Somecity</City>
                <State>NY</State>
                <Zip>67890</Zip>
            </Address>
            <PhoneNo>987-654-3210</PhoneNo>
        </Customer>
        <Customer CustomerID="3">
            <Name>Bob Johnson</Name>
            <Address>
                <Street>789 Pine St</Street>
                <City>Othercity</City>
                <State>TX</State>
                <Zip>11223</Zip>
            </Address>
            <PhoneNo>456-789-0123</PhoneNo>
        </Customer>
    </Customers>
    <Orders>
        <Order>
            <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
            <EmpID>100</empID>
            <OrderDate>2022-01-01</OrderDate>
            <Cost>100.50</cost>
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
            <EmpID>101</empID>
            <OrderDate>2022-01-02</OrderDate>
            <Cost>200.75</cost>
        </Order>
    </Orders>
</Root>
```

I want to extract elements from that nested xml string and store it into a csv file. For that I tried with below PySpark Code.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ETL").getOrCreate()


df_Customers_Orders = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("source.csv")
df_Customers_Orders.show(truncate=False)
# For removing the enclosing of xml string within double quotes
df_Customers_Orders = df_Customers_Orders.withColumn(
    "Data", expr("substring(Data, 2, length(Data)-2)")
)
df_Customers_Orders = df_Customers_Orders.withColumn(
    "Data", regexp_replace("Data", '""', '"')
)
df_Customers_Orders.show(truncate=False)

df_sample_CustomersOrders1 = df_Customers_Orders.selectExpr(
    "xpath(Data,'/Root/Customers/Customer/@CustomerID') as CustomerID",
    "xpath(Data,'/Root/Customers/Customer/Name') as ContactName",
    "xpath(Data,'/Root/Customers/Customer/PhoneNo') as PhoneNo",
)


df_sample_CustomersOrders1.show(truncate=False)

df_sample_CustomersOrders1.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").mode(
    "overwrite"
).save("path.csv")
```

But when I am trying to display the df_sample_CustomersOrders1, it is not what I was expecting.

```
+----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|CustomerID                  |ContactName             |PhoneNo                 |
+----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
|[GREAL, HUNGC, LAZYK, LETSS]|[null, null, null, null]|[null, null, null, null]|
+----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

Why is it getting array of null values for ContactName and PhoneNo? Cant the xpath function can be used to returns the text contents of xml node or for only to return the values xpath can be used

Comment: XML tags are case sensitive. you can use a xml viewer to spot errors : ``` <CustomerID>1</customerID>``` C cap at the first one.

Comment: please do not change your question when answered. If you have something else to ask, then ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You're missig the  `text` instruction. See official doc : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.xpath.html?highlight=xpath

```py
df.selectExpr(
    "xpath(Data,'/Root/Customers/Customer/@CustomerID') as CustomerID",
    "xpath(Data,'/Root/Customers/Customer/Name/text()') as ContactName",
    "xpath(Data,'/Root/Customers/Customer/PhoneNo/text()') as PhoneNo",
).show()

+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|CustomerID|         ContactName|             PhoneNo|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
| [1, 2, 3]|[John Doe, Jane S...|[123-456-7890, 98...|
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: But in the above dataframe, column contains a array of values only.

Comment: @GovindSajeev just [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode)

Comment: But I can't explode all the columns in a single step, while exploding each column step by step, final no of rows are more than the expected( records are getting repeats).
df_sample=df_source.select(explode('Country').alias('Country'),'ContactTitle','CustomerID','Phone','Region')
df_sample=df_sample.select('Country',explode('ContactTitle').alias('ContactTitle'),'CustomerID','Phone','Region')
df_sample=df_sample.select('Country','ContactTitle',explode('CustomerID').alias('CustomerID'),'Phone','Region')

Comment: @GovindSajeev You should probably look at the [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/index.html). The function you're looking for is [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip.html?highlight=zip#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip)